# Shiny reactive values based on different reactive values

Tags: r, shiny, reactive, shiny-reactivity

I have a reasonably complex shiny app I'd like to break into modules. 
There are two dataframes (`a` and `b`) created in two separate modules. A third module is used to create a large dataframe with many new variables (`new_data`) based on dataframes `a` and `b`. The new_data dataframe is then used by another two modules to further wrangle `new_data` and output two dataframes `c` and `d`.

The code runs, but instead of getting two dataframes for `c` and `d`, I get an error: `"data" must be 2-dimensional (e.g. a data frame or matrix)`. If I change `new_data` into a reactiveValue the code crashes. Is this possible and good a good use of reactivity?

```
### Libraries
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(DT)   
library(shinyjs)

### Data----------------------------------------

table_a <- data.frame(
  id=seq(from=1,to=10),
  x_1=rnorm(n=10,mean=0,sd=10),
  x_2=rnorm(n=10,mean=0,sd=10),
  x_3=rnorm(n=10,mean=0,sd=10),
  x_4=rnorm(n=10,mean=0,sd=10)
) %>% 
  mutate_all(round,3)

table_b <- data.frame(
  id=seq(from=1,to=10),
  x_5=rnorm(n=10,mean=0,sd=10),
  x_6=rnorm(n=10,mean=0,sd=10),
  x_7=rnorm(n=10,mean=0,sd=10),
  x_8=rnorm(n=10,mean=0,sd=10)
)%>% 
  mutate_all(round,3)


### Modules------------------------------------ 

mod_table_a <- function(input, output, session, data_in,reset_a) {

  v <- reactiveValues(data = data_in)
  proxy = dataTableProxy("table_a")

  #set var 2
  observeEvent(reset_a(), {
    v$data[,"x_2"] <- round(rnorm(n=10,mean=0,sd=10),3)
    replaceData(proxy, v$data, resetPaging = FALSE) 
  })

  # render table
  output$table_a <- DT::renderDataTable({

    DT::datatable(
      data=v$data,
      editable = TRUE,
      rownames = FALSE,
      class="compact cell-border",
      selection = list(mode = "single", 
                       target = "row"
      ),
      options = list(
        dom="t",
        autoWidth=TRUE,
        scrollX = TRUE,
        ordering=FALSE,
        bLengthChange= FALSE,
        searching=FALSE
      )
    )
  })

  return(v)

}

mod_table_b <- function(input, output, session, data_in,reset_b) {

  v <- reactiveValues(data = data_in)
  proxy = dataTableProxy("table_b")

  #reset var
  observeEvent(reset_b(), {
    v$data[,"x_6"] <- round(rnorm(n=10,mean=0,sd=10),3)
    replaceData(proxy, v$data, resetPaging = FALSE)  # replaces data displayed by the updated table
  })

  # render table
  output$table_b <- DT::renderDataTable({

    DT::datatable(
      data=v$data,
      editable = TRUE,
      rownames = FALSE,
      class="compact cell-border",
      selection = list(mode = "single", 
                       target = "row"
      ),
      options = list(
        dom="t",
        autoWidth=TRUE,
        scrollX = TRUE,
        ordering=FALSE,
        bLengthChange= FALSE,
        searching=FALSE
      )
    )
  })

  return(v)
}

mod_new_data <- function(input,output,session,tbl_a,tbl_b){

  v <- reactiveValues(
    data = data.frame(id=seq(from=1,to=10)) %>%
      left_join(tbl_a$data,by="id") %>%
      left_join(tbl_b$data,by="id") %>%
      mutate(
        y_1=x_1+x_6,
        y_2=x_2+x_5
        )
  )
  # 
  # v <- reactive({
  #   data.frame(id=seq(from=1,to=10)) %>%
  #     left_join(tbl_a$data,by="id") %>%
  #     left_join(tbl_b$data,by="id") %>%
  #     mutate(
  #       y_1=x_1+x_6,
  #       y_2=x_2+x_5
  #     )
  # })

  return(v)
}


mod_table_c <- function(input, output, session, data_in) {

  data_out <- reactive({
    data_in$data %>%
      select(x_1,x_2,y_1)
  })

  # render table
  output$table_c <- DT::renderDataTable({

    DT::datatable(
      data=data_out,
      editable = TRUE,
      rownames = FALSE,
      class="compact cell-border",
      selection = list(mode = "single", 
                       target = "row"
      ),
      options = list(
        dom="t",
        autoWidth=TRUE,
        scrollX = TRUE,
        ordering=FALSE,
        bLengthChange= FALSE,
        searching=FALSE
      )
    )
  })
}

mod_table_d <- function(input, output, session, data_in) {

  data_out <- reactive({
    data_in$data %>%
      select(x_4,x_6,y_2)
  })

  # render table
  output$table_d <- DT::renderDataTable({

    DT::datatable(
      data=data_out,
      editable = TRUE,
      rownames = FALSE,
      class="compact cell-border",
      selection = list(mode = "single", 
                       target = "row"
      ),
      options = list(
        dom="t",
        autoWidth=TRUE,
        scrollX = TRUE,
        ordering=FALSE,
        bLengthChange= FALSE,
        searching=FALSE
      )
    )
  })
}

modFunctionUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  DT::dataTableOutput(ns(id))
}


### Shiny App---------
#ui----------------------------------
ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    br(),
    column(1,
           br(),
           actionButton(inputId = "reset_a", "Reset a")
    ),
    column(6,
           modFunctionUI("table_a")
    ),
    column(5,
           modFunctionUI("table_c")
    )
  ),
  fluidRow(
    br(),
    br(),
    column(1,
           br(),
           actionButton(inputId = "reset_b", "Reset b")),
    column(6,
           modFunctionUI("table_b")
    ),
    column(5,
           modFunctionUI("table_d")
    )
  ),
  #set font size of tables
  useShinyjs(),
  inlineCSS(list("table" = "font-size: 10px"))
)

#server--------------
server <-  function(input, output) {

  #table a
  tbl_a_proxy <- callModule(module=mod_table_a,
                            id="table_a",
                            data_in=table_a,
                            reset_a = reactive(input$reset_a)
  )

  #table b
  tbl_b_proxy <- callModule(module=mod_table_b,
                            id="table_b",
                            data_in=table_b,
                            reset_b = reactive(input$reset_b)
  )

  #new data
  new_data <- callModule(module=mod_new_data,
                           id="new_data",
                           tbl_a = tbl_a_proxy,
                           tbl_b = tbl_b_proxy
                           )

  #table c
  callModule(module=mod_table_c,
             id="table_c",
             data_in=new_data
  )

  #table d
  callModule(module=mod_table_d,
             id="table_d",
             data_in=new_data
  )

}  

#app----------------------------------
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: `data=data_out` to be replaced with `data=data_out()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your example is a little complicated, and I think you're potentially running into several issues. With this particular code, the modularization seems more like a hindrance than a help, since it would be more straightforward to just call everything directly in the server code, but I understand that this is theoretically a reduced example (albeit still complex).

I'll start off by addressing your basic question:
**"Is this possible and a good use of reactivity?"**

In Shiny, all code that's executed (directly or indirectly) by the server portion MUST be reactive. So the question is not really "should I or should I not use reactive code", but **"which type of reactive code is most appropriate?"**

The simplest form of reactivity is a call to `reactive()`, like so:

```
x <- reactive({
    some code
})
```

The value of x depends on whatever code is present within x, including other reactive values. However, x does NOT behave like a normal non-reactive r variable; it is more akin to a function (or a "closure"). **To source it in other code, you must follow it with parentheses**, like so:

```
x2 <- reactive({
    x() ^ 2
})
```

Thus, by correcting your syntax (adding parens) you can accomplish what you're trying to accomplish with `reactive()` alone.

`reactiveValues()`, meanwhile, is generally not preferred over `reactive()`, but it does have some advantages. The best use is in defining side effects. In other words, `reactive()`, like a typical function, can only return a single value (though that value can be a list or other complex data type). But, if you need a function to change the value of a side-effect variable before returning its final value, you can use `reactiveValues()`, like so:

```
statuses <- reactiveValues()
x <- reactive({
    if (someval > 1) {
        statuses$square <- TRUE
        xval <- z ^ 2
    } else {
        statuses$square <- FALSE
        xval <- z
    }
}
```

So that all said, I went ahead and "fixed" your code to change your reactive variables to `reactive()` and to reference them properly with parentheses. Now, all of your tables are displayed properly. That said, there are still some other non-trivial issues with your code, such that it is not actually "doing" what it's supposed to do (tables c and d do not update with changes to a and b, and the "reset" buttons don't work). I haven't addressed these issues, but here is at least some revised code to get the tables to work.

```
### Libraries
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(DT)   
library(shinyjs)

### Data----------------------------------------

table_a <- data.frame(
  id=seq(from=1,to=10),
  x_1=rnorm(n=10,mean=0,sd=10),
  x_2=rnorm(n=10,mean=0,sd=10),
  x_3=rnorm(n=10,mean=0,sd=10),
  x_4=rnorm(n=10,mean=0,sd=10)
) %>% 
  mutate_all(round,3)

table_b <- data.frame(
  id=seq(from=1,to=10),
  x_5=rnorm(n=10,mean=0,sd=10),
  x_6=rnorm(n=10,mean=0,sd=10),
  x_7=rnorm(n=10,mean=0,sd=10),
  x_8=rnorm(n=10,mean=0,sd=10)
)%>% 
  mutate_all(round,3)


### Modules------------------------------------ 

mod_table_a <- function(input, output, session, data_in,reset_a) {

  v <- reactive(data_in)
  proxy = dataTableProxy("table_a")

  #set var 2
  observeEvent(reset_a(), {
    v()[,"x_2"] <- round(rnorm(n=10,mean=0,sd=10),3)
    replaceData(proxy(), v(), resetPaging = FALSE) 
  })

  # render table
  output$table_a <- DT::renderDataTable({

    DT::datatable(
      data=v(),
      editable = TRUE,
      rownames = FALSE,
      class="compact cell-border",
      selection = list(mode = "single", 
                       target = "row"
      ),
      options = list(
        dom="t",
        autoWidth=TRUE,
        scrollX = TRUE,
        ordering=FALSE,
        bLengthChange= FALSE,
        searching=FALSE
      )
    )
  })

  return(v)

}

mod_table_b <- function(input, output, session, data_in,reset_b) {

  v <- reactive(data_in)
  proxy = dataTableProxy("table_b")

  #reset var
  observeEvent(reset_b(), {
    v()[,"x_6"] <- round(rnorm(n=10,mean=0,sd=10),3)
    replaceData(proxy(), v(), resetPaging = FALSE)  # replaces data displayed by the updated table
  })

  # render table
  output$table_b <- DT::renderDataTable({

    DT::datatable(
      data=v(),
      editable = TRUE,
      rownames = FALSE,
      class="compact cell-border",
      selection = list(mode = "single", 
                       target = "row"
      ),
      options = list(
        dom="t",
        autoWidth=TRUE,
        scrollX = TRUE,
        ordering=FALSE,
        bLengthChange= FALSE,
        searching=FALSE
      )
    )
  })

  return(v)
}

mod_new_data <- function(input,output,session,tbl_a,tbl_b){

  v <- reactive(
    data.frame(id=seq(from=1,to=10)) %>%
      left_join(tbl_a,by="id") %>%
      left_join(tbl_b,by="id") %>%
      mutate(
        y_1=x_1+x_6,
        y_2=x_2+x_5
      )
  )
  # 
  # v <- reactive({
  #   data.frame(id=seq(from=1,to=10)) %>%
  #     left_join(tbl_a$data,by="id") %>%
  #     left_join(tbl_b$data,by="id") %>%
  #     mutate(
  #       y_1=x_1+x_6,
  #       y_2=x_2+x_5
  #     )
  # })

  return(v)
}


mod_table_c <- function(input, output, session, data_in) {

  data_out <- reactive({
    data_in %>%
      select(x_1,x_2,y_1)
  })

  # render table
  output$table_c <- DT::renderDataTable({

    DT::datatable(
      data=data_out(),
      editable = TRUE,
      rownames = FALSE,
      class="compact cell-border",
      selection = list(mode = "single", 
                       target = "row"
      ),
      options = list(
        dom="t",
        autoWidth=TRUE,
        scrollX = TRUE,
        ordering=FALSE,
        bLengthChange= FALSE,
        searching=FALSE
      )
    )
  })
}

mod_table_d <- function(input, output, session, data_in) {

  data_out <- reactive({
    data_in %>%
      select(x_4,x_6,y_2)
  })

  # render table
  output$table_d <- DT::renderDataTable({

    DT::datatable(
      data=data_out(),
      editable = TRUE,
      rownames = FALSE,
      class="compact cell-border",
      selection = list(mode = "single", 
                       target = "row"
      ),
      options = list(
        dom="t",
        autoWidth=TRUE,
        scrollX = TRUE,
        ordering=FALSE,
        bLengthChange= FALSE,
        searching=FALSE
      )
    )
  })
}

modFunctionUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  DT::dataTableOutput(ns(id))
}


### Shiny App---------
#ui----------------------------------
ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    br(),
    column(1,
           br(),
           actionButton(inputId = "reset_a", "Reset a")
    ),
    column(6,
           modFunctionUI("table_a")
    ),
    column(5,
           modFunctionUI("table_c")
    )
  ),
  fluidRow(
    br(),
    br(),
    column(1,
           br(),
           actionButton(inputId = "reset_b", "Reset b")),
    column(6,
           modFunctionUI("table_b")
    ),
    column(5,
           modFunctionUI("table_d")
    )
  ),
  #set font size of tables
  useShinyjs(),
  inlineCSS(list("table" = "font-size: 10px"))
)

#server--------------
server <-  function(input, output) {

  #table a
  tbl_a_proxy <- callModule(module=mod_table_a,
                            id="table_a",
                            data_in=table_a,
                            reset_a = reactive(input$reset_a)
  )

  #table b
  tbl_b_proxy <- callModule(module=mod_table_b,
                            id="table_b",
                            data_in=table_b,
                            reset_b = reactive(input$reset_b)
  )

  #new data
  new_data <- callModule(module=mod_new_data,
                         id="new_data",
                         tbl_a = tbl_a_proxy(),
                         tbl_b = tbl_b_proxy()
  )

  #table c
  callModule(module=mod_table_c,
             id="table_c",
             data_in=new_data()
  )

  #table d
  callModule(module=mod_table_d,
             id="table_d",
             data_in=new_data()
  )

}  

#app----------------------------------
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks Joe, that works. You're right this is just a **simple** example of a larger app.

Answer (score 1):

If you convert (as you had) the `mod_new_data` to a reactive:

```
mod_new_data <- function(input,output,session,tbl_a,tbl_b){

  # v <- reactiveValues(
  #   data = data.frame(id=seq(from=1,to=10)) %>%
  #     left_join(tbl_a$data,by="id") %>%
  #     left_join(tbl_b$data,by="id") %>%
  #     mutate(
  #       y_1=x_1+x_6,
  #       y_2=x_2+x_5
  #     )
  # )
  # 
  v <- reactive({

    # browser()
    data.frame(id=seq(from=1,to=10)) %>%
      left_join(tbl_a$data,by="id") %>%
      left_join(tbl_b$data,by="id") %>%
      mutate(
        y_1=x_1+x_6,
        y_2=x_2+x_5
      )
  })

  return(v)
}
```

then, in your code `data_in` and `data_out` in modules `C` and `D` are reactives, so you need to call them as that.
Instead of `data_in$data` is `data_in()`, and instead of `data_out` is `data_out()`. The latter is the reason you have the `"data" must be 2-dimensional (e.g. a data frame or matrix)` error, as you were trying to call datatable on a reactive, not on the reactive result.
After that everything works:

```
### Libraries
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(DT)   
library(shinyjs)

### Data----------------------------------------

table_a <- data.frame(
  id=seq(from=1,to=10),
  x_1=rnorm(n=10,mean=0,sd=10),
  x_2=rnorm(n=10,mean=0,sd=10),
  x_3=rnorm(n=10,mean=0,sd=10),
  x_4=rnorm(n=10,mean=0,sd=10)
) %>% 
  mutate_all(round,3)

table_b <- data.frame(
  id=seq(from=1,to=10),
  x_5=rnorm(n=10,mean=0,sd=10),
  x_6=rnorm(n=10,mean=0,sd=10),
  x_7=rnorm(n=10,mean=0,sd=10),
  x_8=rnorm(n=10,mean=0,sd=10)
)%>% 
  mutate_all(round,3)


### Modules------------------------------------ 

mod_table_a <- function(input, output, session, data_in,reset_a) {

  v <- reactiveValues(data = data_in)
  proxy = dataTableProxy("table_a")

  #set var 2
  observeEvent(reset_a(), {
    v$data[,"x_2"] <- round(rnorm(n=10,mean=0,sd=10),3)
    replaceData(proxy, v$data, resetPaging = FALSE) 
  })

  # render table
  output$table_a <- DT::renderDataTable({

    # browser()

    DT::datatable(
      data=v$data,
      editable = TRUE,
      rownames = FALSE,
      class="compact cell-border",
      selection = list(mode = "single", 
                       target = "row"
      ),
      options = list(
        dom="t",
        autoWidth=TRUE,
        scrollX = TRUE,
        ordering=FALSE,
        bLengthChange= FALSE,
        searching=FALSE
      )
    )
  })

  return(v)

}

mod_table_b <- function(input, output, session, data_in,reset_b) {

  v <- reactiveValues(data = data_in)
  proxy = dataTableProxy("table_b")

  #reset var
  observeEvent(reset_b(), {
    v$data[,"x_6"] <- round(rnorm(n=10,mean=0,sd=10),3)
    replaceData(proxy, v$data, resetPaging = FALSE)  # replaces data displayed by the updated table
  })

  # render table
  output$table_b <- DT::renderDataTable({

    # browser()

    DT::datatable(
      data=v$data,
      editable = TRUE,
      rownames = FALSE,
      class="compact cell-border",
      selection = list(mode = "single", 
                       target = "row"
      ),
      options = list(
        dom="t",
        autoWidth=TRUE,
        scrollX = TRUE,
        ordering=FALSE,
        bLengthChange= FALSE,
        searching=FALSE
      )
    )
  })

  return(v)
}

mod_new_data <- function(input,output,session,tbl_a,tbl_b){

  # v <- reactiveValues(
  #   data = data.frame(id=seq(from=1,to=10)) %>%
  #     left_join(tbl_a$data,by="id") %>%
  #     left_join(tbl_b$data,by="id") %>%
  #     mutate(
  #       y_1=x_1+x_6,
  #       y_2=x_2+x_5
  #     )
  # )
  # 
  v <- reactive({

    # browser()
    data.frame(id=seq(from=1,to=10)) %>%
      left_join(tbl_a$data,by="id") %>%
      left_join(tbl_b$data,by="id") %>%
      mutate(
        y_1=x_1+x_6,
        y_2=x_2+x_5
      )
  })

  return(v)
}


mod_table_c <- function(input, output, session, data_in) {

  data_out <- reactive({
    data_in() %>%
      select(x_1,x_2,y_1)
  })

  # render table
  output$table_c <- DT::renderDataTable({

    # browser()

    DT::datatable(
      data=data_out(),
      editable = TRUE,
      rownames = FALSE,
      class="compact cell-border",
      selection = list(mode = "single", 
                       target = "row"
      ),
      options = list(
        dom="t",
        autoWidth=TRUE,
        scrollX = TRUE,
        ordering=FALSE,
        bLengthChange= FALSE,
        searching=FALSE
      )
    )
  })
}

mod_table_d <- function(input, output, session, data_in) {

  data_out <- reactive({
    data_in() %>%
      select(x_4,x_6,y_2)
  })

  # render table
  output$table_d <- DT::renderDataTable({

    DT::datatable(
      data=data_out(),
      editable = TRUE,
      rownames = FALSE,
      class="compact cell-border",
      selection = list(mode = "single", 
                       target = "row"
      ),
      options = list(
        dom="t",
        autoWidth=TRUE,
        scrollX = TRUE,
        ordering=FALSE,
        bLengthChange= FALSE,
        searching=FALSE
      )
    )
  })
}

modFunctionUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  DT::dataTableOutput(ns(id))
}


### Shiny App---------
#ui----------------------------------
ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    br(),
    column(1,
           br(),
           actionButton(inputId = "reset_a", "Reset a")
    ),
    column(6,
           modFunctionUI("table_a")
    ),
    column(5,
           modFunctionUI("table_c")
    )
  ),
  fluidRow(
    br(),
    br(),
    column(1,
           br(),
           actionButton(inputId = "reset_b", "Reset b")),
    column(6,
           modFunctionUI("table_b")
    ),
    column(5,
           modFunctionUI("table_d")
    )
  ),
  #set font size of tables
  useShinyjs(),
  inlineCSS(list("table" = "font-size: 10px"))
)

#server--------------
server <-  function(input, output) {

  #table a
  tbl_a_proxy <- callModule(module=mod_table_a,
                            id="table_a",
                            data_in=table_a,
                            reset_a = reactive(input$reset_a)
  )

  #table b
  tbl_b_proxy <- callModule(module=mod_table_b,
                            id="table_b",
                            data_in=table_b,
                            reset_b = reactive(input$reset_b)
  )

  #new data
  new_data <- callModule(module=mod_new_data,
                         id="new_data",
                         tbl_a = tbl_a_proxy,
                         tbl_b = tbl_b_proxy
  )

  #table c
  callModule(module=mod_table_c,
             id="table_c",
             data_in=new_data
  )

  #table d
  callModule(module=mod_table_d,
             id="table_d",
             data_in=new_data
  )

}  

#app----------------------------------
shinyApp(ui, server)
```